# Test Export / Download file with protractor

Tags: download, directory, protractor, export, default

i got a problem. Can someome help me !
i want to export file from export button in js page and download file to a directory in my project for testing. But i cant change download default_directory. when i run test, it was downloaded in /Downloads , not /resource/download/ directory.
How can i set download directory for protractor
This is my protractor-config.js

```
directConnect: true,
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ["--headless"]
        },
        prefs: {
            'download': {

                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",
                'directory_upgrade': true
            },
        },
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                "--headless",
            ]
        },
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",
                'directory_upgrade': true,
            },
        },
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one,

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/resources/test/download' // change in this place
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: hi @Madhan , i think your code is not different my code @@ i don't understand, bro

Comment: @AquariusPotter The code Madhan has posted has the `prefs` object **within** the `chromeOptions` object. Your issue is likely caused by you having it outside

Comment: hi @DublinDev , thanks for rep. that's is perfect ! thanks Madhan and DublinDev

Comment: @AquariusPotter good to hear. If this has resolve the issue for you could you accept this as the answer to help future users. Thanks

Comment: @AquariusPotter mark the answer as correct if it really helped you to resolve your problem.Thanks

Comment: @DublinDev i got a problem, when i run protractor, chrome pass perfectly , but firefox got error : 
 /home/aquarius/work_spaces/LFR3/html/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:514
[firefox #01]     let err = new ctor(data.message);
[firefox #01]               ^
[firefox #01] WebDriverError: Could not convert pref value to string, boolean, or integer
 From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()

i think my firefox prefs is wrong but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: when i run with not "--headless" in firefox, it show me save as firefox dialog . how can i turn off it